# ViewModel Method Not Reloading View

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with Xamarin.Forms whereby the View is not refreshing as I would expect it to.

I have bound a View to a ViewModel, and I have a series of methods to perform various functions.

On the successful completion of a function, I want it to execute my `LoadResults()` method.

The `LoadResults()` method works fine when I load the view initially. However, when I execute any other method (`DeleteScan(id)` method shown below) it should re-fire the LoadResults() method and reload the page.

I know it is entering the `LoadResults()` method as I've put a break point in there and stepped through it. But by the end of it, it doesn't reload the view.

I also know the view *can* refresh, as I have other simple methods which are simply updating properties in the VM and those changes are reflecting in the UI.

So for whatever reason, `LoadResults()` is not reloading the page.

Any ideas what I've done wrong here?

**View Model Constructor and Properties**

```
public class ResultsProcessViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public ICommand AddTimingCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand AddScanCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand InsertTimingCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand InsertScanCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand DeleteTimingCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand DeleteScanCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand PublishCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand LoadResultsCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand CancelMissingFinisherCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand CancelMissingTimingCommand { get; set; }

        public int RaceId { get; set; }
        public DateTime RaceDate { get; set; }

        //public ResultsViewModel(Race race)
        public ResultsProcessViewModel(Race race)
        {
            AddTimingCommand = new Command<string>(AddTiming);
            InsertTimingCommand = new Command(InsertTiming);

            AddScanCommand = new Command<string>(AddScan);
            InsertScanCommand = new Command(InsertScan);


            DeleteTimingCommand = new Command<int>(DeleteTiming);
            DeleteScanCommand = new Command<int>(DeleteScan);

            PublishCommand = new Command(Publish);

            LoadResultsCommand = new Command<int>(LoadResults);


            CancelMissingFinisherCommand = new Command(CancelMissingFinisher);
            CancelMissingTimingCommand = new Command(CancelMissingTiming);

            Invalid = false;

            PublishStatus = race.ResultStatus;
            Published = false;
            PublishVisibility = false;
            AddTimingVisibility = false;
            AddScanVisibility = false;
            AddVisibility = true;
            IsBusy = false;
            RaceId = race.Id;
            RaceDate = race.RaceDate;
            RaceStartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(race.RaceStartTime);
            Scans = ScansAPI.GetScans(RaceId);
            Timings = TimingsAPI.GetTimings(RaceId);
            Entries = EntriesAPI.GetEntries(RaceId);
            LoadResults(RaceId);
        }

        ObservableCollection<GroupedResultModel> _grouped; 
        public ObservableCollection<GroupedResultModel> grouped 
        {
            get { return _grouped; }
            set
            {
                if (_grouped == value)
                    return;

                _grouped = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Grouped");
            }
        }

        DateTime _raceStartTime;
        public DateTime RaceStartTime
        {
            get { return _raceStartTime; }
            set
            {
                if (_raceStartTime == value)
                    return;

                _raceStartTime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RaceStartTime");
            }
        }

        int _timingPosition;
        public int TimingPosition
        {
            get { return _timingPosition; }
            set
            {
                if (_timingPosition == value)
                    return;

                _timingPosition = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TimingPosition");
            }
        }

        int _addScanTimingId;
        public int AddScanTimingId
        {
            get { return _addScanTimingId; }
            set
            {
                if (_addScanTimingId == value)
                    return;

                _addScanTimingId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AddScanTimingId");
            }
        }

        int _addTimingScanId;
        public int AddTimingScanId
        {
            get { return _addTimingScanId; }
            set
            {
                if (_addTimingScanId == value)
                    return;

                _addTimingScanId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AddTimingScanId");
            }
        }

        int _scanPosition;
        public int ScanPosition
        {
            get { return _scanPosition; }
            set
            {
                if (_scanPosition == value)
                    return;

                _scanPosition = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ScanPosition");
            }
        }

        bool _isBusy;
        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get { return _isBusy; }
            set
            {
                if (_isBusy == value)
                    return;

                _isBusy = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsBusy");
            }
        }

        bool _published;
        public bool Published
        {
            get { return _published; }
            set
            {
                if (_published == value)
                    return;

                _published = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Published");
            }
        }

        bool _publishVisibility;
        public bool PublishVisibility
        {
            get { return _publishVisibility; }
            set
            {
                if (_publishVisibility == value)
                    return;

                _publishVisibility = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PublishVisibility");
            }
        }

        bool _error;
        public bool Error
        {
            get { return _error; }
            set
            {
                if (_error == value)
                    return;

                _error = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Error");
            }
        }

        bool _addVisibility;
        public bool AddVisibility
        {
            get { return _addVisibility; }
            set
            {
                if (_addVisibility == value)
                    return;

                _addVisibility = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AddVisibility");
            }
        }

        bool _addTimingVisibility;
        public bool AddTimingVisibility
        {
            get { return _addTimingVisibility; }
            set
            {
                if (_addTimingVisibility == value)
                    return;

                _addTimingVisibility = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AddTimingVisibility");
            }
        }

        bool _addScanVisibility;
        public bool AddScanVisibility
        {
            get { return _addScanVisibility; }
            set
            {
                if (_addScanVisibility == value)
                    return;

                _addScanVisibility = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AddScanVisibility");
            }
        }

        ObservableCollection<Result> _results;
        public ObservableCollection<Result> Results
        {
            get
            {
                return _results;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_results != value)
                {
                    _results = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Results");
                }
            }
        }

        ObservableCollection<Scan> _scans;
        public ObservableCollection<Scan> Scans
        {
            get
            {
                return _scans;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_scans != value)
                {
                    _scans = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Scans");
                }
            }
        }

        ObservableCollection<Timing> _timings;
        public ObservableCollection<Timing> Timings
        {
            get
            {
                return _timings;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_timings != value)
                {
                    _timings = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Timings");
                }
            }

        }

        ObservableCollection<RaceEntry> _entries;
        public ObservableCollection<RaceEntry> Entries
        {
            get
            {
                return _entries;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_entries != value)
                {
                    _entries = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Entries");
                }
            }
        }

        bool _invalid;
        public bool Invalid
        {
            get { return _invalid; }
            set
            {
                if (_invalid == value)
                    return;

                _invalid = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Invalid");
            }
        }

        bool _resultsInvalid;
        public bool ResultsInvalid
        {
            get { return _resultsInvalid; }
            set
            {
                if (_resultsInvalid == value)
                    return;

                _resultsInvalid = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ResultsInvalid");
            }
        }

        bool _insertScanVisibility;
        public bool InsertScanVisibility
        {
            get { return _insertScanVisibility; }
            set
            {
                if (_insertScanVisibility == value)
                    return;

                _insertScanVisibility = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("InsertScanVisibility");
            }
        }

        string _validationError;
        public string ValidationError
        {
            get { return _validationError; }
            set
            {
                if (_validationError == value)
                    return;

                _validationError = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ValidationError");
            }
        }

        string _resultsValidationError;
        public string ResultsValidationError
        {
            get { return _resultsValidationError; }
            set
            {
                if (_resultsValidationError == value)
                    return;

                _resultsValidationError = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ResultsValidationError");
            }
        }


        string _missingBib;
        public string MissingBib
        {
            get { return _missingBib; }
            set
            {
                if (_missingBib == value)
                    return;

                _missingBib = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MissingBib");
            }
        }

        string _errorMessage;
        public string ErrorMessage
        {
            get { return _errorMessage; }
            set
            {
                if (_errorMessage == value)
                    return;

                _errorMessage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ErrorMessage");
            }
        }

        public Race SelectedRace { get; set; }

        private bool _raceCountZero;
        public bool RaceCountZero
        {
            get { return _raceCountZero; }
            set
            {
                if (_raceCountZero == value)
                    return;

                _raceCountZero = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RaceCountZero");
            }
        }

        string _aboveBelow;
        public string AboveBelow
        {
            get { return _aboveBelow; }
            set
            {
                if (_aboveBelow == value)
                    return;

                _aboveBelow = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AboveBelow");
            }
        }

        string _aboveBelowPosition;
        public string AboveBelowPosition
        {
            get { return _aboveBelowPosition; }
            set
            {
                if (_aboveBelowPosition == value)
                    return;

                _aboveBelowPosition = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AboveBelowPosition");
            }
        }

        string _publishStatus;
        public string PublishStatus
        {
            get { return _publishStatus; }
            set
            {
                if (_publishStatus == value)
                    return;

                _publishStatus = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PublishStatus");
            }
        }

        string _newBatchCode;
        public string NewBatchCode
        {
            get { return _newBatchCode; }
            set
            {
                if (_newBatchCode == value)
                    return;

                _newBatchCode = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("NewBatchCode");
            }
        }

        string _addHH;
        public string AddHH
        {
            get { return _addHH; }
            set
            {
                if (_addHH == value)
                    return;

                _addHH = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AddHH");
            }
        }

        string _addMM;
        public string AddMM
        {
            get { return _addMM; }
            set
            {
                if (_addMM == value)
                    return;

                _addMM = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AddMM");
            }
        }

        string _addSS;
        public string AddSS
        {
            get { return _addSS; }
            set
            {
                if (_addSS == value)
                    return;

                _addSS = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AddSS");
            }
        }



        string _scanBatchCode;
        public string ScanBatchCode
        {
            get { return _scanBatchCode; }
            set
            {
                if (_scanBatchCode == value)
                    return;

                _scanBatchCode = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ScanBatchCode");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
```

**DeleteScan method**

```
void DeleteScan(int scanid)
        {

            //Do stuff when deleting a scan. It needs to do all this in the observable collection. Then when we submit, we'll update all scans, timings etc with whats in the collection
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {

                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => IsBusy = true);
                    var IsThereConnection = GlobalFunctions.CheckForInternetConnection();

                    if (IsThereConnection == false)
                        throw new Exception("You cannot delete a scan whilst you are offline");

                    //We are good to go
                    else
                    {
                        var deletescan = ScansAPI.DeleteScan(scanid);

                        if (deletescan.Code != "NoContent")
                            throw new Exception("Error deleting scan");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        ValidationError = ex.Message;
                        Invalid = true;

                    });

                    return;
                }
                finally
                {
                    var newscans = ScansAPI.GetScans(RaceId);
                    var sortednewscans = new ObservableCollection<Scan>(newscans.OrderBy(c => c.Position));
                    Scans = sortednewscans;
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => Published = false);
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => LoadResults(RaceId));
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => AddScanVisibility = false);
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => IsBusy = false);

                }
            });


        }
```

**LoadResults Method**

```
void LoadResults(int raceid)
        {

            var results = new ObservableCollection<Result>();

            //Start with the timings
            foreach (Timing timing in Timings)
            {


                var result = new Result();

                //Basic details
                result.RaceId = RaceId;
                result.RaceDate = RaceDate;
                result.Status = "Processing";
                result.BackgroundColour = "White";
                result.ScanTrashVisibility = true;
                result.TimingTrashVisibility = true;

                //Timing Data
                result.TimingId = timing.Id;
                result.TimingPosition = timing.Position;
                result.TimingStatus = timing.Status;
                result.StartTime = timing.StartTime;
                result.EndTime = timing.EndTime;
                result.TimingBatchCode = timing.BatchCode;
                result.TimingBatchPosition = timing.BatchCode + timing.Position.ToString();

                var elapsed = result.EndTime - result.StartTime;

                string elapsedhours = elapsed.Hours.ToString();
                string elapsedminutes = elapsed.Minutes.ToString();
                string elapsedseconds = elapsed.Seconds.ToString();
                string elapsedmillis;
                if (elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString().Length > 2)
                {
                    elapsedmillis = elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString().Substring(0, 2);
                }
                else
                {
                    elapsedmillis = elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString();
                }




                if (elapsedhours.Length == 1) { elapsedhours = "0" + elapsedhours; }
                if (elapsedminutes.Length == 1) { elapsedminutes = "0" + elapsedminutes; }
                if (elapsedseconds.Length == 1) { elapsedseconds = "0" + elapsedseconds; }
                if (elapsedmillis.Length == 1) { elapsedmillis = "0" + elapsedmillis; }



                if((elapsedhours == "00"))
                {
                    result.Elapsed = elapsedminutes + ":" + elapsedseconds + "." + elapsedmillis;
                }
                else 
                {
                    result.Elapsed = elapsedhours + ":" + elapsedminutes + ":" + elapsedseconds + "." + elapsedmillis;
                }


                results.Add(result);
            }

            //Add in the scans
            foreach (Result result1 in results)
            {
                var scan = Scans.Where(p => p.BatchCode == result1.TimingBatchCode)
                                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Position == result1.TimingPosition);
                if (scan != null)
                {
                    result1.ScanId = scan.Id;
                    result1.ScanPosition = scan.Position;
                    result1.ScanStatus = scan.Status;
                    result1.ScanBibNumber = scan.BibNumber;
                    result1.ScanBatchCode = scan.BatchCode;
                    result1.ScanBatchPosition = scan.BatchCode + scan.Position.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    result1.ScanId = 0;
                    result1.ScanPosition = 0;
                    result1.ScanStatus = 99;
                    result1.ScanBibNumber = "UNKNOWN";
                    result1.AddScanButtonVisibility = true;
                    result1.ScanBatchCode = result1.TimingBatchCode;
                }
            }

            //Add any scans which there are no times for
            var notimescans = new ObservableCollection<Scan>();
            foreach (Scan scan in Scans)
            {
                var checkscan = results.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ScanId == scan.Id);

                if (checkscan == null)
                {
                    var newresult = new Result();

                    newresult.RaceId = RaceId;
                    newresult.RaceDate = RaceDate;
                    newresult.Status = "Processing";
                    newresult.ScanId = scan.Id;
                    newresult.ScanPosition = scan.Position;
                    newresult.ScanStatus = scan.Status;
                    newresult.ScanBibNumber = scan.BibNumber;
                    newresult.ScanBatchCode = scan.BatchCode;
                    newresult.ScanBatchPosition = scan.BatchCode + scan.Position.ToString();
                    newresult.ScanTrashVisibility = true;
                    newresult.AddTimingButtonVisibility = true;

                    newresult.TimingId = 0;
                    newresult.TimingPosition = 99999;
                    newresult.TimingStatus = 99;
                    newresult.Elapsed = "N/A";

                    results.Add(newresult);
                }
            }

            //Then add in the entries
            foreach (Result result2 in results)
            {

                var entry = Entries.FirstOrDefault(p => p.BibNumber == result2.ScanBibNumber);
                if (entry != null)
                {
                    result2.EntryId = entry.Id;
                    result2.FirstName = entry.FirstName;
                    result2.LastName = entry.LastName;
                    result2.FormattedName = entry.FirstName + " " + entry.LastName.ToUpper();
                    result2.Gender = entry.Gender;
                    result2.DateOfBirth = entry.DateOfBirth;
                    result2.Club = entry.Club;
                    result2.Team = entry.Team;
                    result2.EntryBibNumber = entry.BibNumber;

                    if (result2.Club == null)
                    {
                        result2.FormattedClub = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result2.FormattedClub = entry.Club.ToUpper();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    result2.EntryId = 0;
                    result2.FirstName = "Unknown";
                    result2.LastName = "ATHLETE";
                    result2.FormattedName = entry.FirstName + " " + entry.LastName.ToUpper();
                    result2.Gender = "Unknown";
                    result2.DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now;
                    result2.Club = "";
                    result2.Team = "";
                    result2.EntryBibNumber = result2.ScanBibNumber + " (Unrecognised)";
                }

                if(result2.ScanBatchCode == "NULLBATCH")
                {
                    result2.ScanBatchCode = "Default";
                }

                if (result2.TimingBatchCode == "NULLBATCH")
                {
                    result2.TimingBatchCode = "Default";
                }



            }


            if(Scans.Count() != Timings.Count())
            {
                ResultsInvalid = true;
                ResultsValidationError = "Your scan count and timing count's don't match. Please continue processing your results until these match and you will then be able to publish.";
            }
            else
            {
                Invalid = false;
                PublishVisibility = true;
            }
            var sortedresults = new ObservableCollection<Result>(results.OrderBy(c => c.Elapsed));
            int newposition = 1;
            foreach (Result sortedresult in sortedresults)
            {
                sortedresult.OverallPosition = newposition;
                newposition = newposition + 1;
            }

            //Create batches
            grouped = new ObservableCollection<GroupedResultModel>();
            foreach (Result result in results)
            {
                GroupedResultModel resultGroup = new GroupedResultModel();

                var groupcheck = grouped.FirstOrDefault(b => b.BatchCode == result.ScanBatchCode);
                if (groupcheck == null)
                {
                    resultGroup.BatchCode = result.ScanBatchCode;

                    var BatchOfResults = results.Where(r => r.ScanBatchCode == resultGroup.BatchCode).OrderBy(r => r.Elapsed);

                    int batchposition = 1;
                    foreach (Result batchedresult in BatchOfResults)
                    {
                        batchedresult.OverallPosition = batchposition;
                        resultGroup.Add(batchedresult);
                        batchposition = batchposition + 1;
                    }

                    grouped.Add(resultGroup);
                }
            }

            Results = sortedresults;    
            OnPropertyChanged("Invalid");
        }
```

Comment: Wrap this line (in the end of `LoadResults` method) '`Results = sortedresults;`' with `BeginInvokeOnMainThread`. It should looks like this: `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { Results = sortedresults;} );`. There are some conceptual mistakes in your way to do such thing, but it should works.

Comment: I agree this code needs a lot of refactoring, which I plan to do once it works. Unfortunately your suggestion has not solved the problem :-/

Comment: It makes sense, indeed. The instance of `ObservableCollection<Result>` you've bound isn't the same anymore when you change the reference from `Results` property. Instead, try to just clean it and re-add the elements.

Comment: I found the issue. I changed the binding. I added a Grouping to the listview in the XAML and of course, the binding changed. So I was trigging the refresh of the wrong property. Changing the `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()` to use the grouped property solved it.